# How could another thread's code run on the main thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, heap-memory, android-handler

Lately, I was confused by some `Android` API. Here is some simplified explanation, cause the code is a little long which is totally right, but just confuse me.

I have two thread: UI thread and another `HandlerThread` called `AThread`.

`mResponseHander` is a `Handler` created in UI thread which obviously associtated to the UI thread's looper. Then I pass the `mResponseHandler` to the `AThread`.

`AThread` is a `HandlerThread` that does some image downloading task. In `AThread`, I wrote some code like this:

```
mResponseHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (mRequestMap.get(target) != url) {
                return;
            }

            mRequestMap.remove(target);
            mThumbnailDownloadListener.onThumbnailDownloaded(target, bitmap);
        }
    });
```

Besides, the variables `mRequestMap` and `mThumbnailDownloadListener` and others are only defined in the `AThread`.

I know when I call `mResponseHandler.post(new Runnable)`, the `Runnable` will later run on the UI thread cause the `mResponseHandler` is associtated to the UI thread's looper.

Here is the question: why the code above running in the UI thread is still right when the variables `mRequestMap` and `mThumbnailDownloadListener` and others are not defined in the UI thread but only defined in the `AThread`?

Comment: It may not be right.  Are `mRequestMap` and `mThumbnailDownloadListener` thread safe, and are the references to them `final`?

Comment: Yes, I think it's thread safe.Becasuse mRequestMap is ConcurrentMap, the references are not final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why the code above running in the UI thread is still right when the variables "mRequestMap" and "mThumbnailDownloadListener" and others are not defined in the UI thread but only defined in the AThread?

Any class instance (lets use "object" further) resides in the `JVM` `heap` (not "in threads" or anything else). When applying the `new` operator as

```
Type variableName = new Type();
```

a piece of memory is allocated on the heap and reference to the memory is stored as value of `variableName`. From now on, any object (e.g. a `Thread` object or an object that implements `Runnable`, like in your case) that has the reference (`variableName` or its copy) to the `Type` object, can "operate" on it.

With that said, by posting the `Runnable` to the handler associated with the `Looper` of the UI-thread you tell the thread what job should be done with the objects that reside in the heap and can be referred by `mRequestMap` and `mThumbnailDownloadListener`.

For the reference: [Java Memory Model](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/java-memory-model.html).